# PostGis - st_union polygons, keep sum of attribute

Tags: postgis, postgresql, fields-attributes, dissolve, union

My current query is:

```
    SELECT
        (ST_Dump( ST_Union( way ) )).geom AS way,
        10000 AS way_pixels
      FROM (
        SELECT
          way,
          way_pixels,
        FROM polygons
      ) AS test
```

it works fine to obtain and dissolve and split into indivisual polygons. But is there a reasonable way to compute sum of way_pixels attribute over merged polygons?

For example polygons A, B, C were merged. A has way_pixels value of 20, B of 120 and C of 19. So I want merged polygon to have way_pixels set to 159, not 10000 as it is done currently.

Computing sum has a known problem. With overlapping rather than joining polygons it is going to produce misleading values. But it is preferable to assuming that size is always 10000.

ST_Area is not solution as way_pixels values are not real area but projected area (in Web Mercator).

[Merge two polygons, attributes are added - Tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65577/merge-two-polygons-attributes-are-added-tool) and [Sum of attributes in Spatial join when polygons cross boundaries in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163708/sum-of-attributes-in-spatial-join-when-polygons-cross-boundaries-in-arcmap) [Sum attribute in overlapping polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133866/sum-attribute-in-overlapping-polygons) are similar but about ArcGis

Comment: I asked a similar question here but would be curious if anything has changed: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106793/how-to-union-polygons-and-add-attribute-values-of-combined-output-features